What kind of sensor can detect a touch contact with at least 5 mm resolution on large area?
Looking around and in the help section it seems my question is on-topic here. If I'm wrong, please tell me and I'll delete it.
For a teaching activity I was asked to develop a "plate" of about 200x300 mm where children can put their hands on. The plate should recognize the touch contact and highlight the contour area with RGB LEDs. Nice-to-have but not mandatory, is to detect the amount of "pressure" exerted, or said in other words, how close are the body parts to the plate.
For the specific application (I mean, not from a technical point of view, but due to the teaching activity background) we cannot use optical devices.
My first thought was to use a grid of capacitive sensors, with an addressable chain of RGB LEDs in between. This seems very hard to achieve due to the minimum resolution requested: 5 mm. It would mean 5 mm from center-to-center of each capacitive PAD sensor. Even if it is possible, it's not trivial (I have to place, connect and handle over 2400 sensors). Furthermore, with such a tiny and close PADs there is very little room for the LED placement. Anyway, this would be solved putting them on the bottom layer upside-down with just a little hole to allow the light to pass.
Probably it might work, but as said is not trivial and there are so many issues with the layout, routing and firmware handling of all these capacitive sensors. On the other side, I can also detect the "pressure" (aka distance) since most capacitive touch controllers can output debug raw data - not only the on-off status.
Is there another kind of technology I can use?
Just as side note, the capacitive solution is quite good since I can put a glass panel over the PCB to be easily cleaned.

Why wouldn't you just use a capacitive or resistive digitizer as used on LCD panels?

"I have to place, connect and handle over 2400 sensors" A PCB + EMS will do that for you.

@winny, I was talking about the design of the PCB, taking care about the cross-interferences of the sensors and all the signal lines and the data to be acquired by the firmware

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany because I'm not aware about how they work! If you would explain a bit more your proposal in an answer I'll gladly upvote it and evaluate it!

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany, after a quick googling, if I understand correcty the resitive digitizer can detect only one touch, while capacitive can be multi-touch, but potentially in my use-case I should be able to detect all the 2400 sensors independently

Okay, I think COTS display digitizers are not suitable in that case.

I think you got yourself quite a challenge, there. My first approach would be a hybrid approach. Capacitive array for range and multitouch and another resistive matrix for touch. However, you may run into limitations, since the resistive grid usually isn't capable of multitouch. Maybe with an advanced controller, you can do sensor fusion magic and only poll the resistive array in areas where the capacitive array senses proximity?

I haven't tried an array of capacitive sensors, but unless you need multitouch and high update speed, could you multiplex them and just scan though your matrix, enable and sense them one by one? IR LED+detector could perhaps be an option too.

@S_G to be clear, the capacitive grid would be enough: the "touch" is detected as the most high values. My question was just to avoid the mess of the layout... but at least in theory it should work, not sure down to 5 mm though

@Mark considering touch screens larger than what you need exist, and their resolution is much better than 5mm, yeah, that's not the problem. Simply get a touch panel, then. Other than that "educational context, so can't to optical sensing" sounds very wrong. Sure you can, you just don't point a camera at something that shows personal properties, but that wouldn't be helpful to your problem, anyways. Typically, you would do something like illuminate a thick piece of glass or acrylic from the side, using the fact that light gets totally reflect on the outer surface when that surface interfaces

Think "modular". From your description, the functionality basically involves one sensor and its associated LED, with the only "global" function being some sort of latch or clear signal. You can get small MCUs that can handle 16 independent touch inputs, so make a 4×4 module that processes 16 sensors and 16 LEDs, and lay them out in a 10×15 array behind your glass.

air; when it interfaces "hand", it starts scattering the light. You set your camera up looking from the inside at the glass, and its iris and lens to a very narrow field of depth at said outer surface. Faces would be physically impossible o make out from the camera picture, as they'd be extremely out of focus, but the shape of things contacting the surface are sharp. (Problem with kids is that surface dirt also contributes)

@MarcusMüller thanks for the hint, but in the question is clearly stated that "we cannot use optical devices" such as cameras, scanners, etc...

@Mark yes, exactly that's what I'm addressing. The claim "we're in an educational environment, so we can't use optical devices" is just wrong. The smoke alarm in your classroom is an optical device, as well, for example.

@MarcusMüller it's not "wrong" it's just the request of the teacher. We're not talking about smoke alarms, but about this specific device that should not be based upon optical devices. That's all.

well, not my call to make, indeed, but I think it would be easier to talk to the teacher and talk about the misconception that any optical device would be able to watch them or the children than to technically work around that misconception. However, as said, this is perfectly well solvable using touch panels, so go for that; a Rpi/Laptop/… + webcam + piece of glass + bunch of LEDs solution might IMHO still be easier, but since a viable technical alternative exists, you can go for it :)

You can consider a grid of FSRs.

minimum resolution requested: 5 mm. It would mean 5 mm from center-to-center ... 10 mm center-to-center would give you 5 mm resolution

research how capacitive fingerprint readers work ... maybe the technology can be made larger

"Glass panel" and "children" may not go together well, especially as they're being encouraged to press it. Maybe polycarbonate would be a safer option.

I know that this may be unwinnable but "due to the teaching activity background) we cannot use optical devices." is understood but misguided. Try this simple and highly informative test: Place your face ON a photocopier glass in close contact and make a copy of your face. Now make copies with your head 50mm and 100mm above the glass. You will find that the "on the glass" copy makes "grotesque and can be fun images" that are essentially unrecognisable as a given person. The 50mm and 100mm copies will be a black/blurred wholly unintelligible mess.  ...

... It is IMPOSSIBLE to image faces with a surface scanning system desiged to detect objects on the glass surface. It would be possible to build a scanning camera system that looked out into a room BUT it's easier for people to hide cameras in other ways. Something designed with eg infrared LEDs to do this task has no risk of being a secret image acquirer.

A potentially practical system that meets your needs at lower cost than almost anything else is a POV (Persistence of vision) system with a spinning disk i=or arm that has arow of detectors (capacitve/optical / ...) and a line of LEDs that are modulated at high speed to produce an image map.

Many POV examples here

Far easier to implement that functionality without sensors would be to use a HF glow discharge! Use plasma-state, not solid-state electronics.
This was used in pseudoscience Kirlian imaging, and might be implemented using a flat-plate electrode, argon fill, and phosphors painted over flat top glass.
The resolution would be better than 100 µm, and it would also be immune to ESD, unlike solid-state devices.

Exciting idea. Yet I doubt A 200x300 uniform electric field and vapour disposition coated panels are the cheapest solution. Not to speak about the High voltage supply and gas containment.

@S_G True - but the op doesn't want the various cheapest solutions avaiable. They have proposed a solutuon space that eliminates such solutions due to an (apparent) misconception by persons unknown of their perceived issues.
